# Validating an if statement with two conditions

Tags: php, validation

I'm trying to validate a form. The form has a simple if statement. What is wrong with this please? The browser says: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&&'` . Both the variables being checked are separate fields. They must both be numbers & not empty.

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {  
if(empty($numberwelds)) && (empty($conwelds)) {
echo " One or both of the numbers are empty ";
} else if(!is_numeric($numberwelds)) && (!is_numeric($conwelds)) {
echo "Data entered was not numeric";
} else {
echo "it passed";
}
}
```

I'm still getting ' one or both of the numbers are empty', even if they both are numbers. My new code:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {  
if(empty($numberwelds) || empty($conwelds)) {
echo " One or both of the numbers are empty ";
} else if(!is_numeric($numberwelds) || !is_numeric($conwelds)) {
echo "one or both of them is not a number";
} else {
echo "it passed";
}
}
```

Thank-you

Comment: your parentheses are off. On both if and else if lines you have too many closing parentheses before the '&&'. It thinks your if statement is done.

Comment: @johnsoe please can you explain in a bit more detail? I'm very new to coding. Thank-you.

Comment: @mattnewbie, I think johnsoe meant that you have prematurely closed the if in the first condition. Try to change it to `if(empty($numberwelds) && empty($conwelds))` and `if(!is_numeric($numberwelds) && !is_numeric($conwelds))` and see if both changes helps.

Comment: @alvits Thanks , but I'm still having a problem with it. New code is pasted above.

Comment: @johnsoe thanks, but i'm still having a problem. New code is above. Thanks for the support!

Comment: @mattnewbie - Syntax is ok. I tested and it passed. Have you checked if the variables are indeed non-empty? Try to print their values before the `if` statement.

Comment: @alvits I've tried storing numbers in the variables in the same script and it works. So I must have a problem with the form part.  I'm using a POST. The action is pointing to the following: `$theurlforform = plugins_url( 'tabsoneformvalidate.php' , __FILE__ ) ; <form method="get" action="<?php echo $theurlforform ?>"> ` Thanks again! Any ideas please?

Comment: @alvits I know what i've done now! I created the two variables on another page. But I haven't used a  session, cookie, post or get to pass the variables over to the next page! Rookie mistake! Thanks.

Comment: @mattnewbie - I'm glad you resolved it. It's still a good learning experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is on the lines where you have;

```
if(empty($numberwelds)) && (empty($conwelds)) {...
```

and,

```
} else if(!is_numeric($numberwelds)) && (!is_numeric($conwelds)) {
```

you are basically trying to create an if statement of the form;

```
if(stuff in here) && (stuff in here){..
```

This is a syntax error because if statements need to be followed immediately by a bracketed control flow, and in your example you have an if statement followed by &&.
All you need to do is add some more brackets to make a correct if statement, for example;

use

```
if((stuff in here) && (stuff in here)){...
```

instead of

```
 if(stuff in here) && (stuff in here){..
```

Comment: Thanks, but i'm still having a problem. I've pasted the new code above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your error output *`One or both of the numbers are empty`* to be accurate, you have to use `||` and not `&&`

What's happening is even if one of the options is empty, the if statement is ignored. And `&&` means *both* statements must be true. An `||` means the *either-or* OR *both* must be true.

As far as the syntax error, the other answered solved it for you.